# How to determine and distinguish between a series and a parallel connection?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Can you tell me what the differences are between those? Also, Can you tell me how to know which one is parallel or series connection if any exercise doesn't give any picture of them?

Comment: Two circuit elements, A and B, are in series if there is no junction between the output terminal of A and input terminal of B. The two elements are plugged right into each other, if an electron goes through A, it goes through B and visa versa.

Parallel means that the input terminals of A and B are in contact and the output terminals of A and B are in contact.

Comment: -1. Lack of research effort. Explanations are easily found in textbooks, on the internet, or in the Related Questions on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question.In case, resistors are given without voltage source then consider any point  and apply this same logic
[image]

[image]